Is it possible to create one type from another and change the keys in TypeScript?
Let's say that I have a type in TypeScript
type IOne = {
    alpha: string,
    bravo: number,
    charlie: Record<string, boolean>
}

I can create another type based on the previous one and change the values, passing them to a generic, for example.
type ITwo = {
    [K in keyof IOne]: MyGeneric<IOne[K]>
};

My question is: can I create one type from another and change the keys?
Is it possible to do something like this:
// Does not work
type IThree = {
    [`${K in keyof IOne}-foo`]: IOne[K]
};

// Desired outcome:
/*
type IThree = {
    "alpha-foo": string,
    "bravo-foo": number,
    "charlie-foo": Record<string, boolean>
};
*/


Use key remapping:
type IThree = {
    [K in keyof IOne as `${K}-foo`]: IOne[K]
};


@JamesLong you should mark this as the accepted answer as I'd say is the exact thing you were looking for.  Marking answers rewards experts with points.  I know it is not much, but is the reward for their efforts.

@JoséRamírez That was the plan, but I had to wait for a few minutes before I could. Thanks for the reminder
